# Why do I get less metadata when using Facebook Graph API with long-lived page-token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to store posts from FB pages in an Elasticsearch cluster. I am using the Logstash plugin 'http_poller' to retrieve data from Facebook's graph API. During testing, I used a user access token in the query string that kept expiring. I extended the access token for my application, but the data I get back looks quite different. It seems like the user access token returns individual posts with metadata (like, the page name which is what I need); whereas using the page token returns a giant chunk of statuses that don't include as much metadata.

I've been googling for hours and hours on what changes to make to my query string which right now looks like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/[id-of-company-FB-page]/feed?access_token=[my-long-lived-page-access-token]

Any help appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using access token from different apps?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. At first I was using the Graph API Explorer to generate a user access token. Now I am using the Page token for my Facebook application.

Comment: You need to ask for the fields you want, using the `fields` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of googling, just have a look at the docs, and it's all there:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#reading (see "Choosing fields")
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/post/

So, a request could be

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/[id-of-company-FB-page]/feed?fields=id,message,created_time,link,picture,place&access_token=[my-long-lived-page-access-token]
```

See [an example in the Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=mashable%2Ffeed%3Ffields%3Did%2Cmessage%2Ccreated_time%2Clink%2Cpicture%2Cplace&version=v2.5)

Comment: Many thanks @Tobi. This is exactly what I needed to see.