# Get facebook user feed with long-lived token offline

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I could convert my short-lived token to long lived token and be able to store it in database..

Thing is, when am trying to fetch data with that long-lived access token offline like id, name, description, likes through below call..

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me/accounts?access_token=".$longkey.""
 echo $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$fbid."/feed?fields=id,name,description,message,likes&limit=10000&since=".$frmdate."&until=".$todate."&access_token

Am getting below errors,
"message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
message "Error validating access token: This may be because the user logged out or may be due to a system error."

I checked the expiration of access token in access token debug tool and i still got 60 days expiration time.

Help would be appreciated...

Comment: Did you just append `&access_token` to the end of the second URL, as your poorly formatted code (please go read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) suggests, or did you supply an actual value as well?

Comment: If it is bad practice, i believe many developers using same formatting..for reference,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352834/why-do-i-get-less-metadata-when-using-facebook-graph-api-with-long-lived-page-to?rq=1

Comment: Please suggest the best practice...if I missed any??

Comment: I meant your formatting of code in this very question.